# Rename ordered x-axis labels in faceted ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'm trying to rename faceted, ordered, x-axis tick marks in `ggplot()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(256)

myFun <- function(n = 5000) {
  a <- do.call(paste0, replicate(5, sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE), FALSE))
  paste0(a, sprintf("%04d", sample(9999, n, TRUE)), sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE))
}

n <- 15
dat <- data.frame(category = sample(letters[1:2], n, replace = T), 
                  name = myFun(n), 
                  perc = sample(seq(0, 1, by = 0.01), n, replace = TRUE))

to_plot <-
  dat %>% 
  group_by(category) %>%
  arrange(category, desc(perc)) %>%
  top_n(5, perc)
```

Plotting this gets me

```
to_plot %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = perc)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~category, scales = "free_y") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

which is unordered and not what I want at all, so I do some ordering by adding a "dummy" column of `row_number()`

```
to_plot %>%
  mutate(row_number = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(row_number = row_number %>% as.factor()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = row_number, y = perc)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~category, scales = "free_y") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

This gets me close, but I still need to change the names on the x-axis so I add:

```
  scale_x_discrete(name = "name", labels = str_wrap(to_plot %>% pull(name), 3))
```

but this only repeats the first facet group across both facets, even though the data in each plot is correct

[image]

I've also tried just ordering everything sequentially and allowing both axes to be `free` in the `facet_wrap()` fx, but that doesn't seem to work either:

```
new_plot <- 
  dat %>% 
  group_by(category) %>%
  arrange(category, desc(perc)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(row_number = row_number() %>% as.factor())


new_plot %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = row_number, y = perc)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "name", labels = new_plot %>% pull(name)) +
  facet_wrap(~category, scales = "free") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

How can I label the x-axis tick-marks in multiple `facet_wrap()` plots independently of one another? I feel like I'm missing something pretty basic here, but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
to_plot %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name %>% forcats::fct_reorder(-perc), y = perc)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~category, scales = "free") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: And if you ever have situations where the same name appears in multiple facets, but you still want to order within each facet, here's a solution for that: https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/ordering-categories-within-ggplot2-facets

Comment: I KNEW it was something simple. Thanks.

Comment: Addendum: `tidytext::reorder_within()` is a nice automatic way to handle facet-specific ordering.